# Checking the Oracle SQL DECODE function result against 0

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, decode

I'm looking at some old PL/SQL code and I have dozen of DECODE functions written like this:

`DECODE(value_1, value_2, 1, 0) = 0`

Now, I know these DECODEs make comparison between *value_1* and *value_2* and they return true or false based on the outcome of comparison. But, for the love of coding, could someone please tell me what's the logic behind **= 0** part? Why is it necessary to check the return value against 0?

Comment: It checks whether value_1 is equal to value_2 or not. And then, as far as I can see, it compares the result with 0, and this troubles me.

Comment: Yes, that should be the case, but there's no conditional statements in the code.

Comment: Presumably this is part of a `where` clause in a SQL statement and only tangentially related to PL/SQL programming? Perhaps the original developer preferred it to the more standard `case` syntax because it simplified the handling of nulls. We are speculating without some more context, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If `value_1 = value_2`, then decode returns `1`
- otherwise, it returns `0`

Therefore, the whole expression checks whether `value_1` is different from `value_2` and then - I presume - does *something*.

If it is part of PL/SQL, you could rewrite it to

```
if value_1 <> value_2 then...
```

---

Some examples:

```
SQL> declare
  2    value_1 number := 5;
  3    value_2 number := 1;
  4  begin
  5    decode(value_1, value_2, 1, 0) = 0
  6  end;
  7  /
  decode(value_1, value_2, 1, 0) = 0
                                 *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 34:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( % ;


SQL> declare
  2    value_1 number := 5;
  3    value_2 number := 1;
  4  begin
  5    decode(value_1, value_2, 1, 0) = 0;
  6  end;
  7  /
  decode(value_1, value_2, 1, 0) = 0;
                                 *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 34:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( % ;
The symbol ":= was inserted before "=" to continue.


SQL> declare
  2    value_1 number := 5;
  3    value_2 number := 1;
  4  begin
  5    if decode(value_1, value_2, 1, 0) = 0 then
  6       null;
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /
  if decode(value_1, value_2, 1, 0) = 0 then
     *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 6:
PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'DECODE' may be used inside a SQL statement only
ORA-06550: line 5, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL> declare
  2    value_1 number := 5;
  3    value_2 number := 1;
  4  begin
  5    case when decode(value_1, value_2, 1, 0) = 0 then
  6         null;
  7    end case;
  8  end;
  9  /
  case when decode(value_1, value_2, 1, 0) = 0 then
            *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 13:
PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'DECODE' may be used inside a SQL statement only
ORA-06550: line 5, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL> declare
  2    value_1 number := 5;
  3    value_2 number := 1;
  4    l_decode_result number;
  5  begin
  6    select decode(value_1, value_2, 1, 0)
  7      into l_decode_result
  8      from dual;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, that's right, but what about cheking the DECODE result with 0?

Comment: What about it? The author of that code decided - for some reason - to check whether DECODE returned 0 and - if it did - performed some action. I don't know which one as you didn't post any context *around* that DECODE.

Comment: Thank you, but I just can find any logic behind it in whole code. It just doesn't have any conditional statements in it.

Comment: Well, statement you posted just CAN'T stand by itself. It is meaningless and would raise an error. DECODE can be used only in a SQL statement.

Comment: I think I got it, thank you. It seems it just doublechecks if two values are not the same.

Comment: You're welcome. I posted bunch of examples that show that DECODE just can't be used in an inappropriate way; have a look.